# Primitive roots not divisible by another prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Assume $p$ and $q$ are two distinct odd primes such that $q$ divides $p-1$. Is it true that we always find a primitive root modulo $p$ which is not divisible by $q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be a primitive root modulo $p$.  If $q$ doesn't divide $r$, we're done.  If $q$ does divide $r$, then note that $q$ doesn't divide $p+r$ which is also a primitive root.